# How to create a repeated border for a responsive element?

Tags: html, css, svg, border

**What I want to create:**

- a dotted border on top of each `li`-element
- the size of the dots and margin between them can change by tweaking the CSS or the image/SVG used)
- the width of the `ul` is responsive, so the border's width varies, too
- dots should not be cut/truncated when resizing the viewport, that means only full cirlces should be visible

**tl;dr: I don't want this** to happen (*see the last dot?*) when resizing the viewport:

[image]

I can't think of a way to create this using:

- repeated background image
- a huge (very long) background image
- border-image

**What I got:**

I figured out a way to solve it, but it's really annoying. It works, but I would have to generate hundreds of (unecassary) `span`-elements as I don't know the maximum width of the element.

The idea is very simply: Dots that don't fit, float into the hidden overflow.

**Source**

*HTML*

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
    </div>
    Item 1
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
    </div>
    Item 2
  </li>
</ul>
```

*CSS*

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 60px;
}

ul > li div {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 2px;
}

ul > li div span {
  float: left;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0 4px 0 0;
  background: grey;
}
```

**JSFiddle**

[You can try it here](https://jsfiddle.net/7rdm5vt7/)

Is there a classy way to solve this, like using some nice SVG- or gradient-trick?

Comment: So that's your math behind the *not cut a dot*? How many dots should be than visible? Than happens to the dots when the element resizes?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The (naive) solution I have simply floats the elements into a invisible new row once they won't fit. So the dots never get cut visually.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I want as many dots as necessary be visible (like a border). When you resize the preview in the fiddle you can see the effect. That same as when repeating a background image.

Comment: Yes, "dots" wrapping is possible using elements only. Repeated images / SVG  are not aware of their "dots" so.... AFIAK it's impossible. Example using radial bg: http://jsbin.com/vugiso/1/edit?html,css,output < but yeah it's an image therefore gets cut-off.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan "*AFIAK it's impossible*" - oh boy, it seems that way. I coulnd't think of an alternative solution either. With really small dots, this ain't a problem, but with bigger elements, it starts looking wierd. Thanks for your help and patience with my wording.

Comment: maybe you could use vw or vh units to size a background gradient(radial) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xVazGe or use a pseudo with dots http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jqvKOa in both cases you can play with different colors numbers of dots won't vary here

Comment: @GCyrillus using radial is already in comments. Using vw unit cannot  apply to dots *wrapping*.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan checkout example, background-size applies the vw units, not the gradient

Comment: @GCyrillus com'n, you cannt use vw to tell the dots "now wrap" (disappear). >> see image in Q.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan check example linked and tell me where it is not working :). it's only comments and i appreciate feed back ;) another tricky answer would to use media querie to skip where dots are truncated ... hmmm okay, this is a really bad one

Comment: @GCyrillus man, please read the Q. The dot should at no point result cut-off. OP is looking for a way to actually do something like `border: 10px dotted #aaa; border-dots-margin: 20px;` where logically the latter property (sadly) does not exists in CSS.

Comment: @GCyrillus you'd have to use the same N? of @media which than would result simpler using N? `<span>`s.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan agreed for a fix size(that might varie, i guess that's where i get confused ), there is no clean ways unless to run specific mediaquerie (via sass to swet less) or js to update spacing or numbers of dots :)

Comment: @GCyrillus not sure if a SVG guru might end up with something I don't know, but I see an expensive JS / jQuery the only solution.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i think canva would be a better  option here since javascript is a programming language

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort - it's a tricky one. And that's what I figured, too: "*unless to run specific mediaquerie (via sass to swet less) or js to update spacing or numbers of dots*". But that's heavy I think (for the purpose).

Comment: @GCyrillus Canvas? With canvas you can only create dots into a canvas, than send the generated image as that element background, or as border-image, one for the X and one for  the Y axis. The JS math will than paint the needed number of whole dots depending on W/H. But... than on resize... over and over again. A throttle could help...  Yes, possible. Again. JS.

Comment: Did you try to use the :before/:after pseudo attributes?

Comment: @AllJs No, not yet. I can't figure out a way to make use of them here.

Comment: @lampshade please check out the answer

Answer (score 6):

`border-image` seems like the way to go to me.  You can control the size, and specify that the repeats be rounded to your desired width.

```css
li {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.small {
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 15px 0 0;
  border-image:url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/4127/border.png") 27 27 round;
}

.large {
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 30px 0 0;
  border-image:url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/4127/border.png") 27 27 round;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="small">First list item</li>
  <li class="large">Second list item</li>
</ul>
```

I've used a diamond-form PNG from the MDN site here, but you should be able to create a PNG (or SVG) with your desired dot shape easily enough.

Comment: Thanks, this is close. It seems that it doesn't work properly in Safari. Also Firefox skewing on resize is relative extreme. Chrome does it smoother somehow.

Comment: The firefox display is ok for me ... May be depends on FF version ?

Comment: Still the best solution even though It doesn't work in Safari 8 (didn't test 9) - unfortunately. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using svg :

```js
function getCenterDotPosition( position, dotWidth ) {
  return ( dotWidth / 2 ) + ( position ) * dotWidth * 2;
}
function getRightPosition( position, dotWidth ) {
  return getCenterDotPosition( position, dotWidth ) + dotWidth/2;
}

function getSVG( options ) {
  var width = options.width;
  var height = options.dotWidth;
  var svg = '<svg class="top-dot" width="' + width + 'px" height="' + height + 'px">';
  var left;
  var radius = options.dotWidth / 2;
  var i = 0;
  var right = getRightPosition( i, options.dotWidth );
  while( right < width ) {
    center = getCenterDotPosition( i, options.dotWidth );
    svg += '<circle cx="' + center + '" cy="' + radius + '" r="' + radius + '" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="' + options.color + '" />';
    i++;
    right = getRightPosition( i, options.dotWidth );
  }
  svg += '</svg>';
  return svg;
}

function generateDots() {
  var options = {
    width    : $('ul').first().innerWidth(),
    dotWidth : 2,
    color    : 'grey'
  };
  var svg = getSVG( options );
  $( 'li svg.top-dot' ).remove()
  $( 'li' ).prepend( svg ); 
}


generateDots();
$( window ).resize(function() {
  generateDots();  
});
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 50%;
}

svg.top-dot {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for you effort. Even though this might work, it is even more overhead then the solution in the question, where I simply could clone some 100 elements with JavaScript that float into the hidden space when needed. No code running on resize needed which I always see as a last resort. But still a neat solution that could be made more versatile simply.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and straight forward test it with rest of the browsers and get back to me
[Tested on firefox chrome opera and ie 11].To check it use it in full screen and resize the browser

> round: the image tiles to fill the area, and is rescaled if necessary to avoid dividing tiles.

```css
li {
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: rgba(213, 126, 0, 1);
  list-style: none;
  border-width: 15px;
  border-image: url("http://f.cl.ly/items/0V28170w0f0k3t3S2p0g/dots.svg") 33% round;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First Element</li>
  <li>second Element</li>
  <li>third Element</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply add a `<hr/>` tag above each `<ul>`.
Is this something you was after?

```
<div>
  <hr/>
  <ul> 
    <li>Item 1</li>
  </ul>
  <hr/>
  <ul> 
    <li>Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>



hr{
  width:100%;
  color:#333;
  border-top: dotted 3px;
}

ul > li div span {
  float: left;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0 4px 0 0;
  background: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
li {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.small {
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 15px 0 0;
  border-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esozt.jpg") 30 30 round;
}

.large {
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 30px 0 0;
  border-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esozt.jpg") 30 30 round;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="small">1st list item</li>
  <li class="large">2n list item</li>
  <li class="small">3rd list item</li>
</ul>
```